# Bernoulli Logarithm

Tags: statistics

How does this:

$$\log[\phi^y(1-\phi)^{1-y}]$$

Become this:

$$\log\left(\frac\phi{1-\phi}\right)y + \log(1-\phi)$$

Comment: You use a combination of the rules of logarithms; namely the power rule, the product rule, the quotient rule, and also the fact that $x^{-a} = {1\over x^a}$.

Comment: This is correct only if $\log\left( \frac \varphi {1-\varphi} \right)y$ is construed as $\left( \log \frac\varphi{1-\varphi}\right)y$ and not as $\log \left( \left( \frac \varphi {1-\varphi} \right) y \right).$ I would prefer to write it unambiguously. $\qquad$

Comment: $\log(\phi^y (1-\phi)^{1-y})=\log(\phi^y (1-\phi)^{-y} (1-\phi))=\log((\phi (1-\phi)^{-1})^y (1-\phi))$, now expand out using the log rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beginning with $$\log(\varphi^{y} \ (1-\varphi)^{1-y})$$

Since $\log a^x = x \log a$ and $\log a b = \log a + \log b$ we can rewrite the equation above as

$$y \log\varphi + (1-y) \log (1-\varphi)$$

Multiplying the right hand side of $(1-y) \log (1-\varphi)$ we have

$$y \log\varphi + \log (1-\varphi)-y \log (1-\varphi)$$

Factoring out $y$ we have

$$y (\log\varphi -\log (1-\varphi))+ \log (1-\varphi)$$

Since $\log a - \log b = \log \dfrac {a}{b}$ we get

$$y (\log (\dfrac {\varphi}{\varphi-1})) + \log (1-\varphi)$$

Comment: Ah! So simple. I was overthinking this. Thank you!!

Comment: My pleasure!  This is also true for any base logarithm ($\log_{10}$ and $\ln$).